# Intellij + Docker: Restore deleted files after wrong mount

Tags: java, git, docker

Following problem: I have a Java EE application that runs inside a docker container.
In my run-configurations i have set up a couple of mounts.
Yesterday i tried to mount a single pdf file from my repo, located in my directory for jsf controllers (just for convenience), to the tmp directory in my container.

So eventually in my mounts I wanted to do something like this:
project/.../.../controller/file.pdf /tmp/file.pdf

By accident however, I ended up doing this:
project/.../.../controller/ /tmp/

Obviously all my class files inside the controller directory were mounted to /tmp/ and were deleted from my repo.
After I detected my mistake I deleted all files from my mount since they shouldn't have been there at all but that also meant that they were gone for good.

All those changes are in git, so technically i could try to reverse it, but in my case over 1000 files have been changed by this.

Is there another way to undo this step or am I left with using git and trying to reset the changes?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: You might be able to `git checkout .` to restore an entire directory from source control.